# import module scoped variables into another module

Tags: javascript, node.js

Basically i have a `ge_lan.js` file that i get from a request to an endpoint, and it has a bunch of inline declarations and assignments of of variables (declared with var keyword) and functions.

I want those variables/functions to be  accessible in my `app.js` file.

Is there a way to do it without having to manipulate the `ge_lan.js` file

Comment: No, it's impossible, just like accessing variables inside a closure without manipulating that closure's code is impossible (in the general case). Change your `ge_lan.js` file.

Comment: How exactly do you include the `ge_lan.js` file in the `app.js` file?

Comment: using a require at the beginning of the app.js, the problem is that var declarations keep variables scoped @stdob--